# How to handle an AP Sion that is getting fed?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been getting into matches against AP Sion, and it seems many players have a hard time fighting this champion.

Are there any tips on how to handle this champion?

Answer (score 1):

CC him and burst his shield down, that takes away his entire offense. It is easier said than done, but if you take away his shield then there is really nothing he can do. Cass is personally my favorite champ against him. Her burst + range is really too much for sion as it is almost impossible for him to reach her with his shield still intact. Champions with long range abilities are huge problems for sion since he has to have his shield up for 4 seconds before blowing you up and has to be right next to you so the longer range you have, the longer you can make that distance that he has to travel to get to you.

Comment: Xerath is pretty good at this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Magic resist helps. And if you build a Banshee's Veil, you can negate one of his two damage spells (and it gives you MR).

Answer (score 0):

The way to beat AP Sion is to keep distance when his shield is up and harass him when his shield is down.  Most AP Sions prioritize the Shield over everything else, so in the laning phase his shield is the bulk of his damage that can harass, avoid his shield and you'll come out ahead in most trades.